# How to place a overlay div on another div on hover with grid like design?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to make a grid like design, I want to show a overlay on hover to each div.

The overlay div has two button which should be placed in center.

i tried the below code i believe the logic is  correct but the position of the button and overlay are not placing at the center of the image div.

**Image Without overlay**

[image: Image Without overlay]

**On hover with overlay**

[image: On hover with overlay]

**Html**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="overlay"><div class="bt1"></div><div class="bt2"></div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
<div class="image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/></div>
         <div class="overlay"><div class="bt1"></div><div class="bt2"></div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
<div class="image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/></div>
         <div class="overlay"><div class="bt1"></div><div class="bt2"></div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
<div class="image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="overlay"><div class="bt1"></div><div class="bt2"></div></div>
    </li>

</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
.image{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;

}
.overlay{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 display:none; 
}

ul { list-style: none; width: 100%; }
ul li { display:inline-block; width:150px;}
.image:hover +.overlay {
    display:block;
    background-color:black;
    top:0;
    opacity:0.75;

}
.bt1 {
    background-color:orange;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 0 0 5%;
}
.bt2 {
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    margin:0 5% 0 0;
}
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CqNK/5/) . Image size are changeable so fixed padding to center button may won't help here i think. Can anyone help me on positioning the overlay?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Changed a few things with the positions and also gave a height to the li element cause the img was bigger..

http://jsfiddle.net/4CqNK/8/

```
.image{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;

}
.overlay{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}
.overlay div {
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    top:50%;
    margin:-50% 5px 0 0;
}
ul { list-style: none; width: 100%; }
ul li { position:relative;display:inline-block; width:150px;height:150px;}
li:hover .overlay {
    display:block;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.75;
}
.bt1 {
    background-color:orange;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
.bt2 {
    background-color:green;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```

Comment: What is `.overlay` div here. i tried top value to button with float its is not working.can it be centered?

Comment: is that possible to add button in 2nd row in center?Can you give any clue @caramba

Comment: @sun of course it can be centered, have those buttons always the same size? why is .image in your css height:100px; if the image height is 150px? do you want it to be 100px and to cut the rest of?

Comment: @sun little update but no dynamic widths possible like this: http://jsfiddle.net/4CqNK/12/

Comment: No `.image` height and width are just for testing purpose. Can the `.image` size changed according to the actual image in it. Can be said alternatively like each grid won't be same in height and width. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You first have to be sure that your `.image` and `.overlay` classes are displayed at the same place. So here you should add a `position:relative` in `ul li` and add an `absolute:position` to both classes.

Once you have that, it is easier to place your elements: ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4CqNK/7/))

```
.image{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
 width:150px;
 height:150px;

}
.overlay{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
 width:150px;
 height:150px;
 display:none; 
}

ul { list-style: none; width: 100%; }
ul li { 
    display:inline-block; 
    width:160px; 
    position:relative;
}
li:hover .overlay {
    display:block;
    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.75;

}
.bt1 {
    background-color:orange;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    left:5%; <-- you may have to play with those values if you want to place them somewhere else
    top:30%; <--  same as above
}
.bt2 {
    background-color:green;
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    right:5%;
    top:30%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer +1, giving parent to `relative` and child to `absolute` is nice but may i know why it is blinking on hover?

Comment: Well the problem is that when you add the overlay element, you're not hovering the image anymore since you're hovering the overlay. So it never stops juggling between "hovering" and "not hovering"

Comment: Pointed out correctly May be another way of displaying the overlay on hover will help like caramba proposed. We should try with li hover.@leMoisela

Comment: exactly, `.image:hover` should be changed to `li:hover`, as Caramba correctly proposed !

Comment: Ya but still have doubt like on hovering `li` `.overlay` will come and then am hovering on `.overlay` now how it thinks as i hovering on `li`

Comment: wrong. your overlay element is a sub element of li, so you will still hover li: http://jsfiddle.net/4CqNK/9/

Comment: I did that but doubt theoretically thats why asked:)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41321/discussion-between-sun-and-lemoisela)

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS code below for image:

```
position:absolute;
z-index:-1;
```

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element.

An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed).

My solution: http://jsfiddle.net/xAkJG/1/

Answer (score 0):

Came across this Question and created my own, **flexbox based**, solution. It centers the buttons more nicely!

http://cssdeck.com/labs/83bhrs3v

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/></div>
        <div class="overlay"><div><div class="bt1"></div><div class="bt2"></div></div></div>
    </li>
    <li>
<div class="image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/></div>
                <div class="overlay"><div><div class="bt1"></div><div class="bt2"></div></div></div>

    </li>
     <li>
<div class="image"><img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOVDt.jpg"/></div>
                <div class="overlay"><div><div class="bt1"></div></div></div>

    </li>       
</ul>
```

```css
.image{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}

.overlay{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;

    background-color:black;
    opacity:0.75;    
}

.overlay > div {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}

ul { list-style: none; width: 100%; }
ul li { position:relative;display:inline-block; width:150px;height:150px;}

li:hover .overlay {
    display:block;
}

.bt1 {
    background-color:orange;
    width:80px;
    height:80px;
}
.bt2 {
    background-color:green;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
}
```